# AWS Health Check Restart API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I have an AWS load balancer with 2 ec2 instances serving an API in Python.

If I have 10K request come in at the same time, and the AWS health check comes in,  the health check will fail, and there is a 502/504 gateway error because of instances restart due the to failed health check.

I check the instances CPU usage, max at 30%, and memory maxed at 25%. 
What's the best option to fix this?

Comment: Which EC2 instance? How are you measuring CPU and memory usage? What are the settings for your health check? Add this information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider here:

1. Keep the health check API fairly light, but ensure that the health check API/URL indeed returns correct responses based on the health of the app.
2. You can configure the health check to mark the instance as failed only after X failed checks. You can tune this parameter and the Health check frequency to match your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the EC2 restart from failed health-check by configuring your autoscaling group health-check type to EC2. This will prevent instances from being terminated due to a failed ELB health-check.